# Destination host unreachable using Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, virtualbox

I just need to be able to call service on client from host and vice versa, unfortunately I just can't make it work.

Host: Windows 7 Professional

Client: Windows 7 Professional with Guest Additions 4.3

I've set up a host-only network.

Host ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Link-local IPv6 address . . . : fe80::2901:db57:33a3:d585%11
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.150
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.250

Ethernet Virtualbox Host-only Network: 
Link-local IPv6 address . . . : fe80::c4f6:a7be:24ae:59e7%13
IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . . :

...
```

Client ipconfig:

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.101
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway:

...
```

The firewall on client is turned off, and there is no antivirus. When I try to ping the host from client, it says

```
ping 192.168.56.1
Reply from 192.168.56.101: Destination host unreachable
```

Similar message appears when pinging client from host. I'd like to ask what could the problem be. I'd be thankful for any advice.

EDIT:
route print

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask         Gateway        Interface Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.250    192.168.1.150    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255       On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0       On-link     192.168.1.150    266
    192.168.1.150  255.255.255.255       On-link     192.168.1.150    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255       On-link     192.168.1.150    266
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0       On-link      192.168.56.1    266
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255       On-link      192.168.56.1    266
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255       On-link      192.168.56.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       On-link     192.168.1.150    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       On-link      192.168.56.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       On-link     192.168.1.150    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       On-link      192.168.56.1    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Destination      Netmask          Gateway   Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.250  Default
===========================================================================
```

Comment: show us `route print` from the host.  Either way, you really should be using a NAT or Bridged network type. Host-only is only asking for trouble.

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you for your response, I've added route print, if you could please take a look

Comment: Ok, it looks like your client doesn't have a valid default gateway. it should be 192.168.56.1, but I'm thinking even that won't work with a HO adapter. I don't understand why people want to use HO adapters unless they are creating an entirely isolated network.

Comment: @FrankThomas I've setup the gateway, but it still writes Destination host unavailable. I don't care if the connection is using host-only. I'm using it only because some days ago, it worked with host-only (just one way, but worked). If other option is easier to setup, I don't mind.

Comment: I've updated Virtualbox, and setup host-only again, and now I can access client from host, but I cant access host from client - Request timed out.

Comment: They are all equal in terms of setup in VBox, and Bridged requires the least configuration to work. With Bridged, your VM will pull an IP address from your DHCP server and operate on your LAN exactly as your physical workstations do, so no messing with NAT or routing or firewalls other than the guests (which youd have to do regardless).